# Node.js / SQL: Insert only new values

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a small DB where i insert new data to each column at a different time. Because I'm only inserting one new value, the values for other columns will become NULL. But if thats the case, i want to keep the old value.

My DB looks like this:

[image: my DB]

One solution would be using `coalesce()` i guess, but i'm updating each column dynamically, and so the other column names are unknown.

```
function database_call(request) {
  database.query(request, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

subscribedItem.on("changed", function (dataValue) {
  let databaseAttribute = subscribedItem.itemToMonitor.nodeId.value;
  let databaseValue = dataValue.value.value;
  databaseAttribute = databaseAttribute.substring(databaseAttribute.indexOf('.')+1)
  databaseAttribute = databaseAttribute.replace(".", '');
  databaseAttribute = databaseAttribute.replace(/"/g, '');
  database_call("INSERT INTO Prozessdaten ("+databaseAttribute+") VALUES ("+databaseValue+")");
});
```

Comment: Could you add some information? Like an example of what happens right now e what would you obtain?

Comment: this code is inserting values like its shown in the database above. i don't know how to implement the coalesce() method dynamically because you need to know each others row attribute name.

Comment: What you're saying is that you don't know all the columns available in the table when doing your code? Because that's not a case I'd expect in a database that uses SQL.

Comment: i know all columns available but I'm only updating one column value at a time (as you see in the picture)...

 I'm not receving any new values for other columns. I need to keep the previous value for columns which I'm not updating. I could solve this by querying the previous database record. but thats inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this](https://lukevers.com/2017/12/28/mysql-vertical-coalesce) that implements a 'vertical' coalesce.

You should first do a query like this, using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to obtain the latest not-null value available in the database for each column.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(05Hz ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR '@@INDEX@@'), '@@INDEX@@', 1) AS 05Hz,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(5Hz ORDER BY updated_at DESC SEPARATOR '@@INDEX@@'), '@@INDEX@@', 1) AS 5Hz
FROM
    table
LIMIT 1
```

After that, update the single value you really need to update and perform an insert specifying all the values for every column.